# MockComponent still includes the actual component

Tags: angular, testing, mocking, ng-mocks

In my unit test I'm doing the following (via @ngneat/spectator):

```js
    const createComponent = createComponentFactory({
        component: AppComponent,
        detectChanges: false,
        declarations: MockComponents(IgxToastComponent, NgxUiLoaderComponent),
        imports: [
            CommonModule, IgxToastModule, RouterTestingModule, NgxUiLoaderModule,
            MockComponent(HeaderComponent)
        ],
        mocks: [ToasterService]
    })
```

The `HeaderComponent` is a standalone component and so per the instructions on the ng-mock site I included it in the imports.  When I run my tests though, I'm getting errors from the construction of the `HeaderComponent` since it include other services that this component doesn't use/mock. My understanding is that by using `MockComponent` it should have faked out the component so that even though the html still has `<app-header>` it doesn't actually try to load the `HeaderComponent`.

Am I supposed to be doing something differently?

I'm using ng-mocks 14.0.1

Comment: It looks that something in your particular setup doesn't work well. A similar boilerplate works as expected: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-moon-o9ble5?file=/src/test.spec.ts. Could you create a min repo with the issue and report it on github: https://github.com/ike18t/ng-mocks/issues/new/choose ?

Comment: Could you share decoration of the `AppComponent`? Is it standalone? I can assume, if it's standalone, then your description is expected behavior, and you need to use MockBuilder to get correct mock of imports.

Comment: Yes everything is standalone. Sorry haven’t been able to create a small sample showing this yet. I’ll try to look at the builder you mentioned when I wake up tomorrow.

Comment: If AppComponent is standalone, it means it uses own import of HeaderComponent, and ignores what is imported in the parent module. You need to use MockBuilder(AppComponent). It mocks internal dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your components are standalone, you need to use [`MockBuilder`](https://ng-mocks.sudo.eu/api/MockBuilder). It will keep `AppComponent` as it is, whereas its imports will be mocked:

```js
// building TestingModule definition
const dependencies = MockBuilder(
  [AppComponent, RouterTestingModule],
).build();

const createComponent = createComponentFactory({
  component: AppComponent,
  detectChanges: false,
  mocks: [ToasterService],

  // adding dependencies where AppComponent is kept,
  // and its imports are mocks
  ...dependencies,
});
```

Comment: I'm not understanding this at all.  If I weren't using HeaderComponent then my code would look like what's in my question, minus the mock of HeaderComponent.   Why does add `<app-header>` to the HTML make me suddenly need to define AppComponent so differently?  What you've shown also doesn't seem to handle the HeaderComponent at all.

Comment: Could you add decoration of the AppComponent to your question? Then I can explain what is happening exactly. Also if you try my suggestion in your project - does it work or still throws?

Comment: So, I did extensive testing with `spectator` and, eventually, it ended up that `MockBuilder` is the easiest way: https://ng-mocks.sudo.eu/extra/with-3rd-party#ngneatspectator-and-mockbuilder. The problem here is that if `AppComponent` is standalone, it uses only own imports, not what a module imports / declares.